# VBA Copy Rows Based on Cell Number, Getting Error with Non-Integers

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code to duplicate each line based on the value in Column O (if it is between 1 and 50).

```
 If ((VInSertNum > 1) And VInSertNum < 50 And IsNumeric(VInSertNum)) Then
       Range(Cells(xRow, "B"), Cells(xRow, "O")).Copy
       Range(Cells(xRow + 1, "B"), Cells(xRow + VInSertNum - 1, "O")).Select
       Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
       xRow = xRow + VInSertNum - 1
    End If
```

And I am getting an error on the last line before End If for some very specific non-integer scenarios.  If the number is 1.9 or higher up to 2, it will create two lines and works fine.  But when the number is lower like 1.4 or less, it keeps trying to duplicate that line to infinity. What's also odd is that numbers like 11.4 or 10.4 or 44.4 work just fine.

Why does it work for some non-integers, but not others?

Comment: Very confused why you are using non-integers at all. Maybe you need to `WorksheetFunction.Round` your numbers.

Comment: If `VInSertNum`, probable declared `As Integer`, is 1.4, rounded at 1, this means that `xRow + 1 - 1 = xRow`...

Comment: The data is from orders and sometimes customers can order 1.4 cases.

Thanks FaneDuru, that makes sense.